# How can you check voice channel id that bot is connected to? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've got a bot that I want to listen to a command only if the user calling it is in the same voice channel. Here is my code.

```
@bot.command(name='leave', help='Disconnects the bot.')
async def leave(ctx):
    user_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    bot_channel =  ctx.guild.voice_client
    print(user_channel)
    print(bot_channel)
    if user_channel == bot_channel:
        client = ctx.guild.voice_client
        await client.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send('You have to be connected to the same voice channel to disconnect me.')
```

However, my issue is that those print lines return different strings. User channel: vc 2, Bot channel: <\discord.voice_client.VoiceClient object at 0x000001D4E168FB20> 
How can I get them both to read the ID of the voice channel so I can compare them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only issue with your code was that you were comparing the user's current voice channel object to the voice client object. You could've added `.channel` to the end of `ctx.guild.voice_client`.

Comparing the two channel objects will do just the same as comparing the channels' IDs. If you really want to compare them by their IDs, then just add on `.id` to each of them.

## Example:

```py
@bot.command(help='Disconnects the bot.')
async def leave(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice.channel and ctx.author.voice.channel == ctx.voice_client.channel:
                                  # comparing channel objects ^

        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send('You have to be connected to the same voice channel to disconnect me.')
```

Please note that I added `ctx.author.voice.channel and` so that you don't run into an attribute error if both the command executor and bot aren't in channels.

If you weren't to check that one of the objects aren't `None`, then you would get an error saying that `NoneType` has no attribute `disconnect()` as the expression `None == None` would be `True` and run the statement.

---

**References:**

- [`Member.voice`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.voice)
- [`VoiceState.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState.channel)
- [`Context.voice_client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.voice_client)
- [`VoiceClient.disconnect()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.disconnect)
- [`VoiceClient.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.channel)

Comment: This was it! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you wouldn't mind [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer, as it'll help others with the same issue find their solution faster! Good luck with the bot :)